# Scaling the Charts Axis (Highcharts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Please have a look at the fiddle:

```
[Fiddle][http://jsfiddle.net/rTRTB/79/]
```

Notice that the values on the Primary and the Secondary axis barely touch the values of 214048 and 3000 respectively. But the y-axis and the secondary Y-axis scalegoes on till 400000 and 4000.

It should scale to the max value rounded of e.g. 3000 in the right axis.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rTRTB/78/

Comment: Looks like your demo doesn't work, could you update that? Morever please use single Highcharts.

Comment: Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rTRTB/79/

Comment: Set alignTicks as false. Addtionally you can set max value on second yAxis (http://jsfiddle.net/rTRTB/79/) or use tickPositioner / tickPositions to prepare better ticks positions. All of functions are documented here: http://api.highcharts.com